# Can I use 6/1 type ac wire to bond my ground rod to my water pipe that is 100 ft away?

Tags: electrical, electrical-panel, grounding

My licensed electrician and city inspector are both asleep as I am ordering the parts to finish a 200 amp service upgrade. Unfortunately, due to the pandemic there is a big shortage on building supplies so I need to order these items immediately.

My home is located in Orange County, CA. My service box is located in the rear of the house and my water pipe enters in from the front of the house.

My electrician asked me to purchase 100ft 6/1 mc cable to run from the new ground rod to the first entry of the water pipe. Unfortunately, I can't find it at all in any of my searches. (Does it even exist?)

Instead, I found 100ft of 6/1 type ac by Southwire (Duraclad) at my local big box store but it indicates its for a "dry location" only.

Is my water pipe still considered a "dry location" since it only gets damp when the water is sometimes running? Should I upgrade to 4/1 type ac because the span is 100ft?

Also, my water pipe runs a quick 90 degree into my garage, can I bond it to the water pipe inside the garage and drywall over it since it is still within 5 ft of the entry?

**P.S - I will definitely be contacting my city inspector and ask him these same questions.**

Comment: What amperage is your service?

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel 200 amps, might go with 4/1 since it's just 80 dollars more and I won't have to crawl into the attic space again if I fail inspection!

Answer (score 1):

4/1 would be the best solution. However when you bond to the water pipe do it where it enters the building. Be sure there are no joints between your ground connect and the pipe coming in. Tests have shown that solder joints can blow apart with a lightning strike.

Answer (score 0):

### Go with the 4/1

You'll need to go with the 4AWG Bare Armored Ground cable for this, since you likely have 4/0 Al (or equivalently, 2/0 Cu) service-entrance conductors for your 200A service.  You won't have issues with it not being a "dry location" as long as you put it inside, by the way.  Also, don't worry about running it in a wall, there's no need to run GECs exposed at all places. (they're often bare wires, so they need the protection of a wall in many cases, even!)

Comment: Would this one suffice? https://www.lowes.com/pd/Southwire-Duraclad-100-ft-4-1-Stranded-Steel-AC-Cable/50101724 and what about rain? There are no plumbing leaks its just when I switch garden hoses it may splash here & there. I am using a 3/0 for the service entrance conductor.

Comment: @user3630509 -- 3/0 copper or 3/0 aluminum? And why is the grounding wire attaching to the plumbing on the outside of the building...?

Comment: 3/0 copper and I thought you were supposed to have a continuous bond from grounding rod to water pipe?

Comment: @user3630509 I take it you're attaching to a pipe on the outside of the house because your ground rod is outside and you don't want to run the grounding electrode conductor thru the wall?

Comment: I can run it inside the wall, I was just under the impression it had to be out and visible at all times. Could I drywall over it?